# TypeError: compute_cross() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'w1', 'w2', and 'w3'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'll try my best to describe this clearly.

I'm having an issue using the `compute_cross` function and it's formatting. 
Here is my current code:(My problem is with the second function)

```
def compute_cross(v1,v2,v3,w1,w2,w3):
    '''Insert docstring here.'''
    try:
        x = round((v2*w3) - (v3*w2), 5)
        y = round((v3*w1) - (v1*w3), 5)
        z = round((v1*w2) - (v2*w1), 5)
        return x, y, z
    except ValueError:
        return None

def compute_face_normal(fp, face_index):
    '''Insert docstring here.'''
    first, second, third = read_face_data(fp, face_index)
    x1, x2, x3 = read_vertex_data(fp, first)
    y1, y2, y3 = read_vertex_data(fp, second)
    z1, z2, z3 = read_vertex_data(fp, third)
    compute_cross(x3,y3,z3)
    return
```

For whatever reason, I'm getting an error message as follows:

```
*TypeError: compute_cross() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'w1', 'w2', and 'w3'*
```

**If I remove x3, y3, and z3 entirely, receive a completely different error. It seems that I am missing some extra parameters.**

These are my intructions:

```
"The vector components (vector coordinates) through two points (initial and terminal points) in
three-dimensional space is calculated as the difference between the coordinates of each point.
```

> For example, if A and B are the initial and terminal points with coordinates (x1,y1,z1) and
>       (x2,y2,z2) respectively, the coordinates of vector AB are:
>       (x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1)
>
> Find the vectors of the two sides and then take their cross product using your compute_cross
>       function."

The function seems to work fine until it reaches `compute_cross`, but I'm totally confused. Thank you dearly for any help.

Comment: Hi picklemaster, where does the compute_cross comes from?

Comment: My mistake, I just edited the post to include compute_cross

Answer (score 0):

Your compute_cross(v1,v2,v3,w1,w2,w3) function takes 6 positional arguments, first trinity (v1-3) represents one vector, second trinity - another.

When you call compute_cross(x3,y3,z3), arguments x3,y3,z3 are assigned to v1,v2,v3 from original signature since they take first three positions in function signature.

Yet compute cross is expecting two vectors (two trinities of coords) when you passing only one set of coordinates.

You have to pass to compute_cross call one more vector.